# Why I get props is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "../articles.css";

const TeamInfo = props => (
  <div className={styles.articleTeamHeader}>
    <div className={styles.left}>
      style={{
        background: `url('/images/teams/${props.team.logo}')`
      }}
    </div>
    <div className={styles.right}>
      <div>
        <span>
          {props.team.city} {props.team.name}
        </span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>
          W{props.team.stats[0].wins}-L{props.team.stats[0].defeats}
        </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default TeamInfo;
```

the code that render this

```
import React from 'react';
import TeamInfo from '../../Elements/TeamInfo';

const header = (props) => {

    const teaminfofunc = (team) => {
        return team ? (
            <TeamInfo team={team}/>
        ) : null
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {teaminfofunc(props.teamdata)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default header;
```

and I am getting error TypeError: props is undefined in line 8 why is that ?

Line 8 is

> background: `url('/images/teams/${props.team.logo}')`

**Update**:

I found that in index.js the `componentWillMount` bring the data correctly but in the `render()` those data (article and team) was not passed to render, any idea why ?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {URL} from "../../../../config";

import styles from '../../articles.css';

import Header from './header';
import Body from './body';

class NewsArticles extends Component {

    state = {
        article:[],
        team: []
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get(`${URL}/articles?id=${this.props.match.params.id}`)
            .then(response => {
                let article = response.data[0];

                axios.get(`${URL}/teams?id=${article.team}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.props.setState({
                            article,
                            team:response.data
                        })
                    })

            })
    }

    render() {
        const article = this.state.article;
        const team = this.state.team;

        return (
            <div className={styles.articleWrapper}>
                <Header teamdata={team[0]} date={article.date} author={article.author} />
                <Body />

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default NewsArticles;
```

Comment: It is very hard to tell from here, try inspecting your component using react dev tools in chrome

Comment: Could you include the code where you are using this component?

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Just log what `props.teamdata` is. It's probably undefined

Comment: @AndyRay article and team has data inside componentWillMount and empty in render. do you know why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You render your component immediately, long before your AJAX call finishes, and pass it the first element of an empty array:

```
<Header teamdata={team[0]}
```

`componentWillMount` does not block rendering. In your render function, short circuit if there's no team to render.

```
render() {
    const { article, team, } = this.state;

    if(!team || !team.length) {
        // You can return a loading indicator, or null here to show nothing
        return (<div>loading</div>);
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.articleWrapper}>
            <Header teamdata={team[0]} date={article.date} author={article.author} />
            <Body />

        </div>
    )
}
```

You're also calling `this.props.setState`, which is probably erroring, and you should never call `setState` on a different component in React. You probably want `this.setState`

Comment: thanks but what is the solution ? I need to get the data from API call then pass it to render what I should do ?

Comment: in other words is there a way to get the data first before render occur ?

Comment: This is the correct pattern for blocking rendering until the data is present, wrapping your component in a data fetching component that doesn't render the child until the data is fetched. You can also return null instead of a loading indicator if you want

Comment: yes but the problem is that in render it always return empty array for article and team data. I tested with console.log several times. please advise

Comment: You're also calling `this.props.setState` instead of `this.setState` which is probably erroring?

Comment: That should have shown up as an error in your console - did it? In general you should never ignore errors or warnings you see in the console

Comment: And this because I am using the bloody Firefox I will use Chrome from now on

Comment: weird, I don't know why firefox would swallow promise errors (it might be as simple as changing a setting) - but I LOVE chrome dev tools, they are fantastic and always getting better

Answer (score 1):

You should always gate any object traversal in case the component renders without the data.

```
{props && props.team && props.team.logo ? <div className={styles.left}>
  style={{
    background: `url('/images/teams/${props.team.logo}')`
  }}
</div> : null}
```

This may not be you exact issue, but without knowing how the prop is rendered that is all we can do from this side of the code.

---

Update based on your edit. You can't be sure that props.teamdata exists, and therefore your component will be rendered without this data. You'll need to gate this side also, and you don't need to seperate it as a function, also. Here is an example of what it could look like:

```
import React from 'react';
import TeamInfo from '../../Elements/TeamInfo';

const header = (props) => (
    <div>
        {props.teamdata ? <TeamInfo team={props.teamdata}/> : null}
    </div>
)

export default header;
```

Answer (score 0):

First -- while this is stylistic -- it's not good practice to pass `props` directly to your functional component. Do this instead.

```
const TeamInfo = ({team}) => (
    <div className={styles.articleTeamHeader}>
        <div className={styles.left}>
            style={{
                background: `url('/images/teams/${team.logo}')`
            }}
        </div>
        <div className={styles.right}>
            <div>
                <span>
                    {team.city} {team.name}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <strong>
                    W{team.stats[0].wins}-L{team.stats[0].defeats}
                </strong>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
);
```

Second, you might just want to do some kind of `null` check. If `team` is `undefined` the first time the component tries to render, you might just want to render `null` so you're not wasting cycles.

In case this isn't the issue, you'd learn a lot by `console.log`-ing your props so you know what everything is each time your component tries to render. It's okay if data is `undefined` if you're in a state that will soon resolve.